# Access the share folder using Python

Tags: python, file, directory, shutil, python-os

```
# Caminho para o arquivo de origem
caminho_origem = 'C:\\TesteScript/'  # Substitua pelo caminho real do arquivo de origem

# Caminho para a pasta de destino compartilhada na rede
caminho_destino = r'\\RAFAEL-DESK\Users\rafa-\Desktop\TesteScript'  # Substitua pelo caminho real da pasta de destino
while True:
    # Lista todos os arquivos na pasta de origem
    for arquivo in os.listdir(caminho_origem):
        caminho_arquivo_origem = os.path.join(caminho_origem, arquivo)
        
        # Verifica se o caminho é de um arquivo (não é um diretório)
        if os.path.isfile(caminho_arquivo_origem):
            ser_imagem = is_image(caminho_arquivo_origem)
            if ser_imagem is True:
                # Monta o caminho para o arquivo de destino na pasta compartilhada
                caminho_arquivo_destino = os.path.join(caminho_destino, arquivo)
                
                try:
                    # Move o arquivo da pasta de origem para a pasta de destino
                    shutil.move(caminho_arquivo_origem, caminho_arquivo_destino)
                    print(f'Arquivo {arquivo} movido com sucesso para {caminho_destino}')
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    print(f'O arquivo {arquivo} não foi encontrado.')
                except PermissionError:
                    print(f'Permissão negada para mover o arquivo {arquivo}.')
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Ocorreu um erro ao mover o arquivo {arquivo}: {str(e)}")
```

And it gives me the following error

> An error occurred when moving file 11.jpg: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\RAFAEL-DESK\Users\rafa-\Desktop\TesteScript/11.jpg'

Can someone help me?

I'm trying to move files from a local folder to a network shared folder via Python

Comment: You're using both "\" and "/" in your directory path

Comment: @SurajShourie While it may be confusing, it shouldn't cause a problem. Windows treats them equivalently.

Comment: Does it help if you include a drive letter in `caminho_destino`?

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621577/errno-22-with-python-shutil-and-move-function

Comment: when you use string with prefix `r` then it treasts \\ as two \ (not single \ ) and this can make problem